# Coq: Show all terms in a type or types in a universe in the environment

Tags: types, coq

Is there a way to display all terms in a type or all types in a universe in the environment?

```
Print Set. (*Syntax error: 'Firstorder' 'Solver' expected after 'Print' (in [vernac:command]).*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use search for an approximation to that. You can do:

```
Search $Type.
```

and get results with type `$Type`. For instance,

```
Search nat -(forall _, _).
```

will show all the terms of type `nat`.

```
Search Set -(forall _, _).
```

Will display all the non-functional terms of type `Set`.
`SearchPattern` should offer similar functionality but I'm not sure. Ssreflect search can do that and more.

Comment: sorry @jaam, what do you mean? The +n form doesn't work in my setup.

Comment: SO doesn't allow comments starting w/ +1, so... :)

Comment: Ah! I thought you meant to replace `-(...)` by `+n` in the _search_ command

Answer (score 2):

The following user-defined tactic can do precisely this, if by environment you mean the proof environment.

```
Ltac printInType t :=
  match goal with
    | [ H : t |- _ ] =>
      idtac H; fail
    | _ => idtac
  end
.

Theorem test : forall n m, n + m = m + n.
Proof.
  intros.
  printInType nat.
  (* prints in the Message window:
     m
     n
  *)
  printInType Set.
  (* prints nothing
     because nat for instance is not explicitely in the proof environment *)
```

What it does precisely is it goes through the proof environment and finds an hypothesis or variable that has the argument type `t`. `idtac H` prints it, then the branch fails because of the [`fail`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.fail) tactic. Now, Coq tries again the same branch on a different hypothesis/variable, consequently all such hypotheses/variables end up being printed. Now, the second branch `| _ => idtac` is just to make sure that the tactic eventually succeeds. If this branch was not there, the tactic would fail with an error and when printing the error, Coq would erase the info it has printed before.

Comment: My question wasn't only about the proof environment but this is useful

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no such functionality in Coq. `Print` will only display the body of the given term, for example:

```
Print plus.
plus = 
fix plus (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => m
  | S p => S (plus p m)
  end
     : nat -> nat -> nat

Argument scopes are [nat_scope nat_scope]
```